# Twin prime based Dirichlet series

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, dirichlet-series

Assuming there are infinitely many twin primes, one can consider a Dirichlet series  $ \sum_{n>0}a_{n}{n^{-s}} $ and replace the sequence of positive integers with the sequence of twin primes. That way such a "twin prime transform" of the Riemann zeta function would give for  $ s=1 $ the so called Brun constant.

What would thus be the abscissa of convergence for such a series assuming the original one is  $ 1 $?

Comment: If the sequence $a_n$ is supported on twin primes, this transform does not change the function and its abscissa. If it is supported on non primes, the transform converges for all $s$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is conjectured that there are $\gg x/\log^2 x$ twin primes up to $x$. If this is the case, then the abscissa of convergence for $\sum_p p^{-s}$, the sum taken over twin primes, is equal to $1$. If there are much fewer twin primes up to $x$ (but still infinite in total), the abscissa of convergence could be anywhere between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would this still hold for any increasing sequence of integers containing  $ \gg_{\varepsilon}x^{1-\varepsilon} $ elements up to  $ x $ for every  $ \varepsilon>0 $?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: Yes, but you can also check this yourself, it is a straightforward exercise in analysis. See also Theorem 1.3 in Montgomery-Vaughan: Multiplicative number theory I.